# How to install WINE on Wubi?

Tags: wubi, wine

I would like to install WINE on my Wubi. I am not good with Linux as I am a new user of ubuntu I thought my first install will be Wubi until I am comfortable with it. Now I want to use a Windows application on Wubi. I read that wine helps in running .exe file on ubuntu but when I try to install on my wubi it says:

> Package dependencies cannot be resolved....This error could be caused
>   by required additional software packages which are missing or not
>   installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software
>   packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Can I get a solution to learn more on this problem? Thank you.

Comment: If you have a 64bit Ubuntu install it could be related to this: http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2013/02/wubi-missing-i386-architecture.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386    
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Note: that this only affects users who installed 64-bit Ubuntu by running wubi.exe standalone. If you installed from the ISO or installed any other flavour e.g. Kubuntu, Edubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Mythbuntu it wouldn't apply.